# Linux kernel timer.. clock_event_device , etc

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel

Could somebody explain to me about linux timer, especially these questions below?

1. If we bring up a new hardware (ARM based), I notice we probably need to register a new timer hardware.  How do we know which timer hardware is used for scheduler or other purposes?
2. Broadcast timer and what it is for?  I notice we need it for waking up from deep-idle (like C3 state) but how does it work to "wake up" the system?
3. How do you register a timer hardware to be broadcast timer?
4. The timer itself probably has a few hardware registered to it (clockevents_register_device)... how do we know which one is used for which?
5. And, what is local timer for and vs. global timer?

Thanks. Any explanation is great. I am just confused here.

Comment: To answer number one, you don't and shouldn't need to know what the timers are being used for. You just register the devices and let the kernel work out what to do with them.